# Нужно ли как-то выделять «Stack Overflow на русском» в тексте?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

На странице удалённого вопроса, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612217/), видим текст:

> Этот вопрос был удалён с сайта Stack Overflow на русском в процессе модерации.

Название сайта «Stack Overflow на русском» никак не выделено в предложении. Хотя, согласно [правилу](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2) кавычки должны быть использованы в частности для:

> названия, связанные со сферой **информационных технологий** (IT), в том числе названия **интернет-ресурсов и веб-сервисов**: *«Словари.ру**», «Грамота.ру», «Яндекс», «**Рамблер»,* **справочно-информационных систем и компьютерных программ**: *системы «КонсультантПлюс», «1С:Предприятие»,* наименования **тарифных планов и услуг**, предоставляемых компаниями – операторами сотовой связи и интернет-провайдерами: *тарифные планы «Единый», «Мобильный»,* *«Профи 1300* *VIP**», «Вызов* *Xtreme**», «Стрим 6», услуги «Кто звонил?», «Мегафон.Бонус», «Сервис-Гид».*

По-моему, как раз наш случай. При этом ситуаций использования названия без кавычек на сайте довольно много. Что скажете?

Comment: Возможно, в подобных фразах вообще опустить название сайта или слово «сайта»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на самом деле, хорошо бы привлечь сюда участников rus.SE для более компетентного обсуждения. Может быть переместить вопрос даже. Хотя в таком случае участникам ruSO будет сложнее заметить тему.

Comment: Ага. У нас огромная проблема отсутствия Меты Мет. Думаю, на Русском языке можно, при необходимости, задать вопрос с точки зрения языка. Если правило существует, оно однозначно и обязательно, то, возможно, вопрос на нашей Мете отпадает сам собой.

Comment: Я думаю, не стоит перемещать тему: это вопрос про наше сообщество на нашей мете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky можно вообще сократить до `Этот вопрос был удалён в процессе модерации.`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В фрагменте предложения `губернатор штата Нью-Орк подписал...` слово "штат" - является [родовым понятием](http://opencorpora.org/manual.php?pool_type=11). Нормы предписывают, что после родового понятия следующее существительное всегда стоит в именительном падеже.

По правилам русского языка допускается опускать родовое понятие:

`Вчера я прочитал "Нос" Гоголя`

или так:

`В его рамках состоялась встреча второй и третьей команд чемпионата : ЦСКА принимал в Москве «Рубин».`

(Как модератор, разметивший в корпусе русского языка более 30 тысяч примеров и проверивший ещё столько же - могу сказать, что в примере с Гоголем будет неснимаемая омонимия между именительным и винительным падежом. Ну это так, к слову.)

Поэтому если очень хочется - можно без колебаний опускать родовые понятия "сайт" ("проект" и т.п.) и в конструкциях с "Stack Overflow на русском".

На здоровье, все конструкции совершенно правильные:

- Сайт "Stack Overflow на русском" объявляет о начале сезона шляп!
- "Stack Overflow на русском" объявляет о начале сезона шляп!
- Stack Overflow на русском объявляет о начале сезона шляп!

В каждом конкретном случае можно выбирать тот вариант, который лучше смотрится.

Например, в фразе "Этот вопрос был удалён с сайта Stack Overflow на русском в процессе модерации" я бы родовое понятие удалять не стал.

Кавычки же здесь более уместны, по более строгим гайдлайнам они нужны.

И, кстати ещё немного. Опускать кавычки при названиях компаний совершенно допустимо, вот [например заголовок пресс-релиза Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/company/services_news/2016/0419_1):

> Яндекс выпустил первый в мире браузер с поддержкой DNSCrypt

Comment: А в блоке контакты внизу `Пресс-служба компании «Яндекс»`. Т.е. можно мешать кавычки с их отсутствием и это нормально? Стало быть менять на ruSO ничего не требуется? И правило не совсем точное, на грамоте.ру или я что-то не учёл?

Comment: @alexolut а) С кавычками более строгий стиль, особенно если кавычки "ёлочками" б) можно смешивать и, да, это нормально в) в некоторых случаях выбор между равноправными вариантами есть чистой воды "вкусовщина" как говорят наши дизайнеры г) в данном конкретном случае лично мне более кажутся уместными кавычки (а Qwertiy'ю - нравится без кавычек), но я не настаиваю д) в целом по сайту можно особо не переделывать ничего, всё достаточно хорошо.

Comment: Просто была как-то [ситуация](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4082/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5#comment13411_4084) со фразой `Stack Overflow на русском на русском ...`

Answer (score 0):

Мне вариант  с кавычками не нравится.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, вашу позицию более развернуто. Есть правило русского языка, которое, как я понял, говорит, что в данном случае следует использовать кавычки.

Comment: @alexolut, не всегда :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, правило там мутное (насколько я помню), а интернет-ресурсы - штука довольно новая и в какую часть правила и почему их решили присобачить - это жирный вопрос.