# Метка [xxx] не существует на этом сайте

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В родительном падеже окончание И должно быть.

Comment: близкий вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4489/213987

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это вполне допустимая конструкция. Имя собственное после родового понятия идёт в именительном падеже (подробнее смотри например [инструкцию корпуса opencorpora](http://opencorpora.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%83_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)):

```
Работы в районе российских сёл Шереметьево, Козловка и др. 

Перестыковка корабля "СОЮЗ ТМА-12"
```

Причём даже на скриншоте видно, что родовое понятие заключено в аналог кавычек — брекеты: метка [sadness]

Так что вполне допустимо было оставить как есть: метка (подлежащее) (что делает?) не существует. Есть подлежащее, есть сказуемое. А за страдательный залог, косвенные предложения Ильяхов бы сказал, что не стоит городить бюрократизмы: подобная речь воспринимается сложнее.

Comment: В некоторых местах так, в некоторых иначе. Меня именно это смущает.

Comment: @Suvitruf тогда надо описывать проблему комплексно, а не отрывать от контекста.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ чуть позже создам отдельный вопрос.